# Move Wiki Pages from one Page library to another using the the "Content and structure" module will set the approval statuses for the pages as "Draft"

Tags: 2013, administration, content-approval, enterprise-wiki, content-and-structure

I have an enterprise wiki site collection inside my sharepoint on-premises 2013. and inside the site collection i created another enterprise wiki sub-site. now on both the root site and the sub-site, i defined that the wiki pages requires content approval as follow:-

[image]

so now the wiki pages can have these 3 built-in Approval Statues; Approved, Rejected or Pending. for example the Pending wiki pages will have this status:-
[image]

now i wanted to move some wiki pages from the root site to the sub-site. so i went to "Site Settings" >> "Site Administration" >> "Content and structure " >> then  i select the related wiki pages >> then from the "Actions" menu >> I click on "Move" >> then i select the Pages library at the sub-site.

now the wiki pages got moved correctly to the subsite's Pages library, but i have noted that their Approval Status will be "Draft", as follow:-
[image]

so is there a way to preserve the wiki pages' original Approval Status ?? not sure what could be causing this ?? now after moving the wiki pages, they preserved everything from versioning, to the system generated columns(such as created, modifed, etc,..). so why the Approval Status did not preserve the original value for the wiki pages??

Answer (score 1):

When Content Approval is enabled any change to an approved item will cause its status to revert from Approved to Draft.  Your wiki pages are approved in the source location, but their addition to the target library counts as a change in the new location, therefore it is correct that their Approval Status would change from Approved to Draft.

Perform the copy again to get around the Approval Status issue.  This time, before copying the web pages, disable the Content Approval feature in the target library.  Copy the web pages over from the source library, and post copy, enable the Content Approval feature in the new library.   When you enable Content Approval in a library with existing content, the existing items will automatically have an Approval Status of Approved. Or, you can just approve the already copied pages in the new target location.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. but in my case if i manually edit an Approved or Rejected wiki page,, its status will be Pending and not Draft ... i will only get the Draft status when i move the wiki pages using the “Content and structure” module ...

Comment: You get Pending or Draft depending on if minor versions are selected in the version settings.  If minor versions are enabled it is a two step process to change the Approval Status to Approved.

Comment: this is the confusion ... as inside my versioning setting i set to have Major versions only.. and whenever i create or edit a wiki page, i get the Pending status.. this is the first time i see Draft version inside my enterprise wiki ... this what makes me confused and hence ask the question.. now the best case scenario i thought of was that the "Approval Status" will not get affected when moving the wiki pages,, but seems this introduced a new status = Draft..

Comment: second point i got.. is now i am confused on what else could be effected when doing the Move ?? is it only the "Approval Status" or there are other properties?? ...

Comment: Double check your versioning settings in your target location.  If you are seeing "Draft" then major and minor versions are enabled.  The approval flow in this configuration is:  Approved -> Draft -> Pending -> Approved/Rejected.  It's a bit confusing in this scenario.  A change sets the file's Approval Status to Draft.  You then have to Publish the file to get to Pending, and then use the Approve/Reject button to complete content approval.

Comment: As for what else can change, many moons ago, in a SharePoint 2010 environment I noted that when using Content and Structure, if metadata does not match in the source and target libraries, the source library metadata overwrites the target library metadata.  I don't know if that was a specific issue to the environment I was working in, the version, etc.